# JSZip in a Loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, jszip

Is it possible to create real zip folders and files with JSZip in a loop, one per element?  If so, how?

Something like this:

```
var JSZip = require("jszip");
const saveAs = require('file-saver');
var fs = require("fs");

for(i = 0; i > 5; i++){
    var zip = new JSZip();
    zip.folder(i).file(i+".txt", i);

    zip
    .generateNodeStream({type:'nodebuffer',streamFiles:true})
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('Zipped Projects.zip'))
    .on('finish', function () {
        console.log("Zipped Projects.zip written.");
    })
}
```

Outside of the loop, an actual zip folder is created with the expected contents in the current directory.  Inside the loop, nothing happens, not even the log.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then this is issue is caused by new `zip` objects being created per loop iteration.

Perhaps you could consider making the following adjustments to resolve this problem:

```
var JSZip = require("jszip");
const saveAs = require('file-saver');
var fs = require("fs");

// Create the single zip object that will be populated
// during the for loop
var zip = new JSZip();

// Populate the zip object with text files per iteration.
// Make sure you update the loop logic to use "i < 5"
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    zip.folder(i).file(i+".txt", i);
}

// Now that the zip object has been populated, write it to
// disk
zip
.generateNodeStream({type:'nodebuffer',streamFiles:true})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('Zipped Projects.zip'))
.on('finish', function () {
    console.log("Zipped Projects.zip written.");
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now that you've explicitly contrasted the async and synchronous parts of the code, I bet you're right.  Unfortunately, however, your code had the same result as mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var JSZip = require("jszip");
const saveAs = require('file-saver');
var fs = require("fs");

var asanaProjects = require("C:/Users/GabrielRivera/Documents/asana/New Projects JSON.json");

async function createProjectZips() {

    var zip = new JSZip();

    asanaProjects.map((project, index, array) => {

        zip.file(project.name+' - '+index+'.json', JSON.stringify(project));        
    })

    zip
        .generateNodeStream({type:'nodebuffer',streamFiles:true})
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('Zipped Projects.zip'))
        .on('finish', function () {
        //console.log("Zipped Projects.zip written.");
        })
}

createProjectZips()
.then(() => {
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: @DacreDenny I figured it out.  Thanks for your help.